# Currency Format in KendoGrid

Tags: javascript, node.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to have Icelandic currency format to be displayed in one of the field in the kendogrid. As I understand, their currency format (#.###) is somewhat different from USD currency - For example:

$1,000.20 will be displayed as 1.000, with 20 cents being truncated, and comma being replaced by full stop. I also do not need the currency symbol in the grid. Can anyone help me out?

The following is the code snippet

```
{
    field: "Discount", 
    title: "MyTotal", 
    format: "{ 0:'c' }",
    attributes: { "class": "editable-cell", style: "text-align: right" } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [changing your culture](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/index)?

Comment: What have you achieved/tried so far? Show some images of your actual + desired result

Answer (score 0):

If the culture of this *one* field is different than the overall culture is use on the page, then you will have to use a custom editor(http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom) for the column as the column configuration does not support a specific culture, but a custom editor using a NumericTextBox gives you all the config options of the NumericTextBox, including culture(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox#configuration).

Define your column like:

```
columns: [
    {
        field: "Discount",
        title: "MyTotal",
        editor: icelandicDiscountEditor, template: "#= Discount #"
    }
```

and the editor(note that you have access to all the configuration options of a NumericTextBox to do as you like):

```
function icelandicDiscountEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoNumericTextBox({
            culture: "is-IS",
            format: "c"
        });
}
```

[Demo of Icelandic format NumericTextBox in Grid vs "Default Culture" NumericTextBox](http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/aWeQo)

Note that in order to use the "is-IS" culture, you must also load the kendo culture JS script in your page, otherwise the culture config will be ignored and the default will still be used.

If the culture of this field is the same as the culture everywhere else on the page, just set the kendo.culture() as Sunny Patel has suggested.